# Create Bootable .iso with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, iso-image, bootable-media

I had a .iso with the installation to Windows 7. I unzipped it and stored the files in a folder on my computer. I use these files, copied onto a USB, to install Windows on my devices. However, now I require the original .iso for a specific installation in VMWare Fusion. I had deleted that and can no longer download it legally. I wish to make a new .iso using the files I have stored in my folder. This needs to be a bootable .iso, so not just any zip-program will work. Do you know a program which can create such a bootable .iso? I am not looking for people telling me to use PowerIso or some other non-bootable end result.

Comment: Just searching `download windows 7 iso` on google will give you tons of links to download it legally on Microsoft servers, I don't get your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN** legally download win7 setup ISOs again.

[Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-Microsoft)

If you really want to do it the hard way, you would use the AIK to repackage the setup files. But lets avoid an XY problem here, stick with just re downloading the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boot disk, then run the setup manually. If you can't find an easy way to access the files from the boot disk, modify the iso so it contains all your Windows setup files as well.

Let me know how it goes.

http://www.allbootdisks.com/download/iso.html

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty easy to do so. u need an ISO tool to create an image file. Then You would have to make a bootable disk to do the installation.Just go to [this](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-create-iso-image-file.htm) website you will find a short tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use oscdimg tool to create a bootable Windows 7 from the files you had extracted.

Download oscdimg.exe and use it this way.

Oscdimg.exe -u2 -bC:\YOUR DIR\expandedSetup\boot\etfsboot.com -h C:\YOUR DIR\expandedSetup C:\YOUR DIR\Win7.iso

If your extracted Windows 7 Installations files are in C:\WinSetup

For example: Oscdimg.exe -u2 -bC:\WinSetup\boot\etfsboot.com -h C:\WinSetup C:\Win7.iso

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71f2c295-213b-43ba-87b8-b2f54e9c7d18/how-make-window-7-professional-download-files-a-bootable-dvd

You could also use cdimage.exe or IMGBurn to do this.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/17061-dvd-iso-build-method-microsoft.html